# My samsung a20 was dropped and the screen is black, can't get the alarm to shut off

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-a20

My samsung a20 was dropped and screen cracked,it worked for a hour or so then screen went completely black...hey google works but can't get the alarm to shut off now...i need all my important information off that device..how do I get the alarm to shut off and if I replaced the screen will everything be the same as before

Comment: if only screen is replaced (but not main pcb board) your data will survive until someone does factory reset. your data is encrypted and protected with screen lock credentials and therefore not accessable